# How to achieve this in excel without circular reasoning?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I want to create an excel page where firstly I have four random numbers between the values 0-9 that update as I want. This is easy by using `=RANDBETWEEN(0,9)` across four cells (A1-D1 for instance). Now is the tricky part I want to have each of these random numbers stop when it reaches a certain value between 0-9 so that if I continually update the formulas if one of the four random number cells reaches a certain value it will stop on that value and then not produce any more random numbers.

So for instance if I set A1 to be `=RANDBETWEEN(0,9)` I can keep refreshing that cell until it becomes a 5 (or any other number 0-9) and then stops.

To achieve this I want to say something like:

```
=IF(A1=5,5,RANDBETWEEN(0,9))
```

of course this doesn't work as it is circular. How can I achieve this in Excel?

Comment: You can allow iterative calculations.  It is an option in the Options menu.

Comment: Hide those cells. Now put formulas in another four cells that refer to them.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do this could you perhaps show me how it would work with the A1 and 5 example I gave above and then I can adapt from there?

Comment: The formula in the other four cells would still need to be circular and refer to themselves to stop and not continue to change.. @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Why the downvote? At least say why so I can try to improve the question! Can't you see I'm new to the site?

Comment: You put the `vba` tag, without showing any effort in vba.  If you want a vba answer then you need to show some effort in resolving your problem in vba.  We help overcome problematic code not write code from scratch.

Comment: Hi Tom, I didn't downvote but I do have a suggestion: can you tell us what you are trying to achieve more broadly? It's highly likely you can go about this a better way.

Comment: @Tom Maybe people who downvoted were expecting you to post the solution also. :)

Comment: @ScottCraner you're right it can't be done in excel formulas it needs to be done in VBA.

Answer (score 4):

In the FILE --> OPTIONS --> FORMULA menu, Enable iterative calculations. with Maximum iterations of `1`

[image]

Then use the formula you suggested:

```
=IF(A1=5,5,RANDBETWEEN(0,9))
```

It will stop when it equals 5 and stay there.

---

Or you can use this function which is similar to @Gary'sStudent

```
Function MyRandBetween(Strt As Long, Ed As Long, Sty As Long) As Long
Application.Volatile
If Application.Caller.Value = Sty Then
    MyRandBetween = Sty
    Exit Function
Else
    MyRandBetween = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(Strt, Ed)
End If

End Function
```

Then your formula would be

```
=MyRandBetween(0,9,5)
```

It will stop at 5 and stay there. Otherwise it will randomly choose a number.

Comment: Btw, any idea what is the idea of `Maximum Change = 0.001`? My understanding is that it allows a change between the circled recalculations of not more than `0.001`, but this is not the case obviously.

Comment: Other way around, it would see 1.0001 as okay in this formula '=IF(A1 = 1,1,RandBetween(10000,10002)/10000)`  as `.0001 is lest than `.001`  It is how accurate we want it to be.  @Vityata

Comment: Thus it is "any change bigger than" `.001`  is allowed. I was understanding it that maximum `.001` change is allowed as max change meant something like this to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this short macro:

```
Sub Leave5Alone()
    With Range("A1")
        If .Value = 5 Then
        Else
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 5)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This can easily be extended for any range of cells and stop-values.

Comment: You may want to consider abstracting the function a bit. Maybe write it as `LeaveAlone(MaxValue as Long)`. This would allow the function to be more useful as changes need to be made.

Comment: @BrandonBarney  You are absolutely correct! I post stuff like this as a **demonstration of technique** rather than a full-blown application...........code can be extended to handle multiple cells..........code can be extended to support multiple limits..............code can be enhanced to include error handling..........etc.